# how to get download progress with unirest-obj-c

Tags: objective-c, unirest

I've been searching but no solution so far.. This is how I made a GET request using Unirest :

```
    [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *simpleRequest) {
        [simpleRequest setUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@location/retrieve_post",C_baseURL]];
        [simpleRequest setHeaders:headers];
        [simpleRequest setUsername:@"username"];
        [simpleRequest setPassword:@"password"];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // This is the asyncronous callback block
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(response.code == 200) {
                // if code is wrong
                BOOL status = [[response.body.object valueForKeyPath:@"callback"] boolValue];
                //            NSLog(@"%d",status);
                if(status) {
                    // display data
                } else {
                    // no data
                }
            }
        });
    }];
```

Is there a way to listen download progress of the response?

Comment: When is your callback block is being called? As soon as the download has been completed or periodically? If the latter, there might be a value within your response object that indicates the overall size of the file (in bytes) as well as the bytes that have been downloaded so far. I'm not sure whether this is available in unirest but it works that way in pure Cocoa.